# SPServices: trying to learn how to use this and jquery, help with example

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jquery, spservices

So I am trying to learn these both as I read nuthin but great things all over the place about them.

So this is what I have from example on codeplex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://espdev:44485/Style%20Library/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://espdev:44485/Style%20Library/jquery/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        var subject = "Hi Subject!";
        var message = "Hi Message!";
        CreateNewItem(subject, message);        
});

function CreateNewItem(subject, message) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "FirstList",
        valuepairs: [["Title", subject], ["Message", message]],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          alert("completed");
        }
    });}

</script>
```

So this doesn't seem to work as I load the page, and as I understand it should. Is there something I am missing? I do have the scriptlinks and have this in a text file in a document library and have a CEWP referencing the file.

Again, I am learning so if there is something of context I missing here I certainly appreicate the help! Thanks!

EDIT: Added the script references to the example; again I also tried the network delivery links in place of the above and got the same results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code. It is working. Are the column names right: Title and Message? Before you test this code with a custom list, try a standard list, like Posts (in Office 365), or Announcements:

```
function CreateNewItem(subject, message) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "Posts",
        valuepairs: [["Title", subject], ["Body", message]],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          alert("completed");
        }
});}
$(document).ready(function() {
        var subject = "Hi Subject!";
        var message = "Hi Message!";
        CreateNewItem(subject, message);        
});
```

Take a look at javascript console in your browser, there you can find useful errors. jQuery and SPServices must be loaded. For your tests you can even use [cdn links for jQuery and SPServices](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/javascript-toolkit-on-text-file/).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Anatoly...thanks for you response. so i changed the references to the ones above that you provided, and checked the console (which is another new thing to me so thanks very much for that!), and I am getting error 'SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'SPServices', so I switched it back to what I had in the style library, and I am getting the same error. I assume this is indicating that the reference to SPService is invalid?

Comment: also...switched to Announcements list and columns Title and Body for testing.

Comment: so I can CTRL+click the references and get to them which says they are good to me, but I still get the error in IE9 as stated above?? I know this has to work because of all the documentation online provided, but if there is something I have overlooked, I can't seem to find it...

Comment: The reference to SPServices seems to be invalid. Does the error occur only in IE9?

Comment: Be sure that wherever you are storing the script files that they are available at least for read for everyone. Also make sure the paths are valid in the browser context and not just in SPD. (Try the URL to the .js file in the browser.)

Comment: @Mark....thank you for your comment (and on side note, I am really anxious after all the content I have read online to start using this :) ). anyway I can get to it in the browser, and this is a dev env on single win7 laptop so I am in under system account because I haven't create any others yet.

Comment: also tried in Firefox....same result.

Comment: It's got to be a reference issue based on what you've listed so far. Can you add the script file references to your post so that we can see those details as well?

Comment: solved. found the issue...once again I appreciate you guys help a rookie! :)

Comment: Puuh! Great! Happy coding!